# ng-Infinite-Scroll never stops always show more and more like a bucle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

Hi I am using [ngInfiniteScrol](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/index.html)  work fine except for 1 thing that when I use it always show more and more never stop, I use request fron a API from NASA and I need that it charge when scroll is in the end of sidebar.

Asteroid Controller

```
(function(){
    angular.module('asteroidCtrl', ['userService', 'asteroidService',  'infinite-scroll'])
        .controller('asteroidsController', function ($scope, AsteroidRequire) {
            $scope.asteroids = new AsteroidRequire();
        });
})();
```

Asteroid service

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('asteroidService', []);
    app.factory('AsteroidRequire', function ($http) {
        var neoAsteroid = function() {
            this.repos = [];
            this.busy = false;
            this.page = 1;
        };
        neoAsteroid.prototype.nextPage = function() {
            if (this.busy) return;
            this.busy = true;
            var url = "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/browse?page=" + this.page + "&api_key=*********************";
            $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
                var items = data.near_earth_objects;
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    this.repos.push(items[i]);
                }
                console.log(this.repos);
                this.page += 1;
                this.busy = false;
            }.bind(this));
        };
        return neoAsteroid;
    });
})();
```

and the view
home.html

```
        <div class="sidebar-table" infinite-scroll="asteroids.nextPage()" infinite-scroll-disabled="asteroids.busy">
            <div class="row list_special" ng-repeat="asteroid in asteroids.repos">
                <div class="[ panel panel-default ] panel-google-plus" ng-click="">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <span class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color: #262626">
                            <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down ]"></span>
                        </span>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" target="_blank" ng-href="{{ asteroid.nasa_jpl_url }}" style="color: #262626">Data Asteroid</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" target="_blank" ng-href="/asteroid/{{ asteroid.neo_reference_id }}" style="color: #262626">About Asteroid</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row list_special" ng-show="asteroids.busy">
                <div class="[ panel panel-default ] panel-google-plus">
                    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                        <h3>Loading .....</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: what version of infinite scroll are you using?

Comment: I install it with bower ---> "ngInfiniteScroll": "^1.2.2"

Comment: I dont think this has been fixed, or if its your issue, but there is a bug in that version: https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll/issues/235
can you try rolling it back to 1.0.0?

Comment: ok I am using the 1.0.0 bow the problem is that no work the "loading" in the ng show

Comment: It's a bug in their library. I ended up using it after facing this issue.